# Convert string to float without loosing decimal places

Tags: string, unity-game-engine, floating-point, type-conversion, rotation

I am having lots of strings that represent rotation values. These strings have 0 to 5 decimal places.

When converting these strings to floats to apply them as rotation values to GameObjects, the float value is always cut short to 4 decimal places. With more than 500 GameObjects, this will result in a huge imprecision over time.

How can I preserve all decimal places?

This is the code I used [modified for better understanding]:

```
myString = "344.93873";
segment.transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler((float)double.Parse(myString), 0f, 0f);
```

What I get is `344.9387` without the `3` at the end. The loss happens here: `(float)double`.

However, when manually rotating objects in Unity3D, I can see rotation values with more than 4 decimal places in the Inspector.

Comment: have you tried directly go through `float.Parse` then?

Comment: also `What I get is` ... what you get where exactly? How do you verify this?

Comment: Yes, I tried that aswell. `float.Parse` and `Single.Parse`
I verify it with `print()`

Like so:
`myString = "344.93873";
myFloat = float.Parse(myString, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
print(myFloat);`

Comment: @doc4 "How can I preserve all decimal places?" --> change goal to "How can I preserve all binary places?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per default [`float.ToString`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.single.tostring?view=net-8.0#system-single-tostring)

> The [ToString()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.single.tostring?view=net-8.0#system-single-tostring) method formats a Single value in the default ("G", or general) format of the current culture.

And further per default for [`float` (=`Single`)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-numeric-format-strings#GFormatString)

> **Single**
>
> Smallest round-trippable number of digits to represent the number (in .NET Framework, **G7 is the default**)

Now your input number

```
344.93873
```

has **8** digits so per default it is clamped to

```
344.9387
```

which has only **7** digits.

A [`float` can have `~6-9 digits`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/floating-point-numeric-types) so in order to be sure to always see the full value you should use

```
print(myFloat.ToString("G9"));
```

---

Besides that: Yes indeed have in mind that either way floating point numbers have a limited precision.

It is very much possible that the exact value of

```
344.93873
```

is **not representable** using a `float`!

See [.Net fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/3EyWjw)

```
double.Parse() => 344.93873000000002093656803481280803680419921875
float.Parse => 344.938720703125
```

Tbh honest though in your use case of angles. There is no way whatsoever, not even in nature anyone will notice a difference of a `0.00001°` angle!

Have in mind that after all Unity is a realtime 3D "Game"-Engine which on purpose drops precision in favor for a faster runtime.

Comment: I'll mark this as answer since you explained it very well and yes: My verification is wrong.
It doesn't solve my initial problem that I get imperfect rotation values which I can tell by looking at the result Unity3D shows me after loading in my file. However, it's a bit difficult to explain here. Thank you!

Comment: I have added a section at the bottom. Yes in general floating point numbers are limited ... only have `8 bytes` to represent any number so c# has to drop precision at some point. But I boldly claim that nobody, not even you can see a difference of `1e-5 °` with the bare eye ;)

Comment: EDIT: Yes, a single 0.00001° deviation is not noticeable but remember, I am stacking hundrets of GameObjects on top. On the other hand.... Maybe something else is causing the imprecision in the result...

Comment: If precision is very crucial for your application I would do all calculations `double` based and only in the final rendering round to float just before applying the results to the scene. Even in a distance of 1000 meters the displacement would only be about `1cm`